# my spidev code does not store the receive data

Tags: spi, c

So i am using a trimmed down version of [this code](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/spi-driver-speed.c) to do a spi transaction usin spidev. Here is my code

```
/*
 * spi-driver-speed.c
 * 2016-11-23
 * Public Domain
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>

/*
spi-driver-speed.c

gcc -o spi-driver-speed spi-driver-speed.c

./spi-driver-speed [bytes [bps [loops] ] ]
*/



int spiOpen(unsigned spiChan, unsigned spiBaud, unsigned spiFlags)
{
   int i,fd;
   char  spiMode;
   char  spiBits  = 8;
   char dev[32];

   spiMode  = spiFlags & 3;
   spiBits  = 8;

   sprintf(dev, "/dev/spidev0.%d", spiChan);

   if ((fd = open(dev, O_RDWR)) < 0)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   if (ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE, &spiMode) < 0)
   {
      close(fd);
      return -2;
   }

   if (ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_BITS_PER_WORD, &spiBits) < 0)
   {
      close(fd);
      return -3;
   }

   if (ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MAX_SPEED_HZ, &spiBaud) < 0)
   {
      close(fd);
      return -4;
   }

   return fd;
}

int spiClose(int fd)
{
   return close(fd);
}

int spiXfer(int fd, unsigned speed, char *txBuf, char *rxBuf, unsigned count)
{
   int err;
   struct spi_ioc_transfer spi;

   memset(&spi, 0, sizeof(spi));

   spi.tx_buf        = (unsigned long)txBuf;
   spi.rx_buf        = (unsigned long)rxBuf;
   spi.len           = count;
   spi.speed_hz      = speed;
   spi.delay_usecs   = 0;
   spi.bits_per_word = 8;
   spi.cs_change     = 0;

   err = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &spi);

   return err;
}

char TXBuf[10] = {0xAB,0xAB,0xAB,0xAB,0xAB,0xAB,0xAB,0xAB,0xAB,0xAB};
char RXBuf[10] = {0};

int bytes = 10;
int speed = 5000000;


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   int fd,er;

   fd = spiOpen(1, speed, 0);

   er = spiXfer(fd, speed, TXBuf, RXBuf, bytes);

   close(fd);


   printf("RX: %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",RXBuf[0],RXBuf[1],RXBuf[2],RXBuf[3],RXBuf[4],RXBuf[5],RXBuf[6],RXBuf[7],RXBuf[8],RXBuf[9]);
   printf("TX: %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",TXBuf[0],TXBuf[1],TXBuf[2],TXBuf[3],TXBuf[4],TXBuf[5],TXBuf[6],TXBuf[7],TXBuf[8],TXBuf[9]);
   printf("ER: %d\n",er);


}
```

but i do not see anything on RXBuf. Am i doing something wrong?

```
RX: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
TX: 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171 171
ER: 10
```

to prove that there is in fact a signal on the MISO here is a snap on the logic analyzer .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like `spi.rx_buf` in `xfer` needs a pointer to the array buffer. `(unsigned long)rxBuf` is not the way i have known to do it.

i suggest to use `uintptr_t` instead of `unsigned long`

```
spi.tx_buf        = (uintptr_t)txBuf;
spi.rx_buf        = (uintptr_t)rxBuf;
```

`uintptr_t` is a datatype meant specifically to hold pointers